# Is there an easier way to let iPadOS do "regional screen shot then copy to clipboard" action?

Tags: screen-capture, copy-paste, ipados

Under Windows 10, you can Win+Shift+S then draw a rectangle on screen to do screen shot, then the screen region in the rectangle will be copied to clipboard. Easy.

Under iPadOS, you have to Cmd+Shift+4, press left-top arrow, drag left-top arrow, press right-bottom arrow, drag right-bottom arrow, click share, click copy, click delete, confirm delete. Too complex for web note-taking then paste to word processors work loads.

Only using mouse and keyboard, not touch.

At least a method for easy "regional screen shot then copy to clipboard" on Safari, but there seems to be no Safari Extention to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a limitation of iPadOS that when invoking a screenshot, it will take the entire screen and then you’ll have to adjust the crop if you don’t want the full image.

iPadOS 16 does have a new feature that should help with your copy to clipboard problem. Instead of having to invoke the share sheet to copy to the clipboard there, if you click the done button there is an option to copy and delete.

[image: screenshot of iPadOS feature to copy and delete screenshot]